# Last batch size in JavaPairDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've got a simple `Spark Streaming` app.
I work with `JavaPairDStreams`. I'd like to know if it's possible to get the last batch size. I need it to complete an operation that I do on each `Tuple2` of the JavaPairDStream.
`JavaPairDStream.count()` method won't work because it just returns a JavaDStream of long, while I just need the last batch size.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the underlying rdd and issue a count on it.

```
dstream.foreachRDD( rdd -> 
   long batchSize = rdd.count();
   ...
)
```

Comment: this will return me all the batch sizes, how can I target just the one I need (the last one)?

Comment: There's no "first" or "last" in Spark Streaming, only "current". This will give you access to the current (latest) batch size.

Comment: ok. But I thought that foreachRDD was applied on all the RDDs.

Comment: @sirdan yes. It's applied on all RDDs that "happen" during the time of the streaming job, but one at the time. The code that you write in a `foreachRDD` will execute every streaming interval, on the data that was collected previously (or offsets, like for direct kafka streams).